# Metal GPU frame time behaves unintuitively

Tags: macos, gpu, intel, metal, objective-c++

i've ran into an interesting performance issue with Metal in my own app which i've been able to reproduce by only making small adjustment to [this example project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/using_a_render_pipeline_to_render_primitives?language=objc). my view has a size of roughly 1600x900 and looks like this:

[image]

there are two draw calls per frame, one for the background and one for the line. the background is made up of 4 vertices and the line is around 2000 vertices. when the scene is drawn like above, Xcode's GPU frame capture tells me that the entire frame takes ~4 ms (!). some observations:

- when the line is drawn first, the frame only takes ~30 µs
- when only the four vertices (that make up the background) are drawn, the frame takes ~3 µs
- when only the line is drawn, the frame takes ~40 µs
- when drawn like above, but with only the first ~900 vertices of the line, the entire frame takes ~4 µs

this doesn't make sense to me. why do the changes described above have such a drastic effect on the frame time? it's a 100x difference.

i'm running the code on a 2018 Mac mini (with Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB), in case that is important.

---

here are the changes made to the demo project:

1. create two `MTLBuffer`s during intitialisation

```objectivec
AAPLVertex quadVertices[] = { ... 4 vertices omitted ... };
quadBuffer = [_device newBufferWithBytes:quadVertices length:4 * sizeof(AAPLVertex) MTLResourceStorageModeManaged];

AAPLVertex dataVertices[] = { ... ~2000 vertices omitted ... };
dataBuffer = [_device newBufferWithBytes:dataVertices length:2000 * sizeof(AAPLVertex) MTLResourceStorageModeManaged];
```

2. draw both buffers in `drawInMTKView`:

```objectivec
[renderEncoder setVertexBuffer:quadBuffer offset:0 atIndex:AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices];
[renderEncoder drawPrimitives:MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangleStrip vertexStart:0 vertexCount:4];

[renderEncoder setVertexBuffer:dataBuffer offset:0 atIndex:AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices];
[renderEncoder drawPrimitives:MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangleStrip vertexStart:0 vertexCount:2000];
```

3. turn on 8x MSAA: `mtkView.sampleCount = 8;` and `pipelineStateDescriptor.sampleCount = 8;`
4. change the render pass's load action to `MTLLoadActionLoad`: `renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = MTLLoadActionLoad;`

edit: [the project is available on my Github](https://github.com/maxjvh/metal-performance-issue).

edit 2: i ran the example project on a 2020 M1 Macbook and there i wasn't able to reproduce any of the bullet points. the total frame time was around 100 µs for the base-case. although, i had to use an MSAA factor of 4 since M1s apparently don't support 8.

---

to be transparent, i've also asked this question on the Apple Developer forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/695245 (i hope that's ok)

Comment: Can you please upload your sample project to GitHub.

Comment: @HamidYusifli sure, here you go: https://github.com/maxjvh/metal-performance-issue

Comment: Have you tried without enabling 8x MSAA in step 3?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock the problem isn't as prominent with lower MSAA sample counts, but that doesn't really answer the question. i would think that 8x MSAA just makes the above-described weirdness more obvious.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it was the answer - I was just trying to get a sense of the issue.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock right! just to elaborate: with 4x MSAA the issue still clearly occurs,  the total frame times are just slightly lower. still in the millisecond range for the base-case though!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a bug, I ran your sample projects on the following processors:

**M1, M1 Pro, M1 Max, Radeon pro 5500M**.

I wasn't able to reproduce your issue.
I suggest you file bug report.

Comment: thanks for testing with all those processors! i have now filed a bug report with Apple, will let you know when i hear back from them.

Answer (score 0):

I can verify, that without 8x MSAA it runs faster. However, 8x MSAA should not result in issues in such a simple project. Why would that be an option?

With an identical machine:

- samplecount 1 => 300 us
- samplecount 2 => 600 us
- samplecount 4 => 1.9 ms
- samplecount 8 => 3.7 ms